# How to access different child view controllers when added on the main view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got a main view controller where I add children on it from different types: IntroViewController and ChapterViewController. I have both of them in my storyboard and this is how I add 10 (my main view controller has a scrollview and when I swipe left, the next view controller(s) show):

```
 for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
     IntroViewController *introViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"];
     [self addChildViewController:introViewController];

 }
```

This function will add 10 viewcontrollers of the type IntroViewController.
But now they have the same name, and I'm not sure how to access these different introviewcontrollers now, for example what if I need to change the 5th view controllers parameters? Something like:

```
     introViewController.initialText = @"test";
```

But since they have the same name I'm not sure how to do this...

Comment: give tad to exch view and access it [myView bringSubviewToFront:[myView viewWithTag:1]];

Comment: I believe *[self childViewControllers];* will return an array with references to all the child ViewControllers. Can you try that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get them with `childViewControllers` property.

From [Apple's doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :

> childViewControllers :
>
> An array of the view controllers that are the children of the receiver in the view controller hierarchy. (read-only)

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *childViewControllers
```

They are indexed the same way as they are into the controller hierarchy. So the 5th viewController created on your loop will be the same as

```
(UIViewController*)[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex: 4]
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the line of code you gave me, normally I would change the text on it like this: introViewController.initialText = @"test"; and how exactly do I need to do it on your way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nvm, its     ((IntroViewController*)[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).initialText = @"Test";

Comment: Relying on an index is pretty awkward.  Is there a way to get a child by name/identifier?

Comment: Of course it is a bad approach to get into the array with a raw index like this, and without bound control. Just to say, the children controller are referenced through an array. So yeah, you can filter your array with the property you want with NSPredicate.